# Pin website to start menu custom icon

Tags: asp.net, windows-8

How do we define a custom icon for websites pined to the windows 8 start menu?

Seems to ignore:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Pinned sites you need to use the following Meta tags to specify the image and background color. Example:

```
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/icon-144x144.png"/>
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#0000ff"/>
```

Tile images must be square PNGs 144px by 144px. For best results, use a transparent background, not a background that matches the tile’s color. The tile color can be specified as a hex RGB color using CSS’s #rrggbb notation, via CSS color names, or by the CSS rgb() function.

Note: IE10 only downloads the tile image when the user pins the site to his or her Start screen so sites don’t incur additional bandwidth costs.

Source:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/06/08/high-quality-visuals-for-pinned-sites-in-windows-8.aspx

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN ( [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg491740(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg491740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ) IE uses the `icon` specified.

Your HTML seems valid, if it isn't appearing I suggest clearing your cache and trying again. Also try deleting your `iconcache.db` file just-in-case.

Note that your `.ico` file must be a real ICO file (rather than a renamed PNG image) and should contain a 16x16, 24x24, and 32x32 sub-images. For Windows 8 there are some additional properites you can set: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg491732(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg491732%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) however these don't relate to the icon.

Comment: It uses the icon when adding to 'favorite' but does not use it when pinning to start menu